# Creme filled doughnuts? Ok at room temp?

Tags: food-safety

So this is probably more of a food-safety question but we purchased some various Krispy Kreme doughnuts yesterday and I ate some of the leftovers today. Some were creme filled and it didn't really dawn on me until now that "maybe" that wasn't a good idea?

So that leads me to ask does creme filled doughnuts need to be refrigerated? I feel like I've eaten tons of leftover doughnuts (creme filled or not) the next day and never gotten sick.

But should I be storing these in the fridge?

Comment: That's very hard to tell without an exact ingredient list.  If the creme was made with artificial vanilla, water and starch: *No need to store in the fridge for the first 24h*.  If made with creme, eggs and flour: *you got lucky!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://s3.amazonaws.com/kkd-e1-images.kktestkitchen.com/ecomm/nutrition/11329-nutrition.pdf, everything in the 'creme' (ugh I hate that word; it is a *cream*, crème is French) in a Krispy Kreme doughnut is shelf-stable. You're fine.

Also, you don't in general want to refrigerate bready/cakey/pastry-y products, unless you will be warming them before eating, due to how moisture and starch interact--you'll end up with a very dry-seeming product.

Comment: The point of using "creme" in English is that "cream" would be a lie. There's little or no dairy in these filings

Comment: The word is also used to describe dairy products. And 'cream' is an adjective; no use of dairy required.

Comment: It's used to describe milk+starch products when those are used as substitutes for dairy cream, but if the filling in a cream cake is real cream, "creme" isn't used (at least not where I am) because real cream sells for more. And the only adjective is "cream**y**" which isn't in consideration. If you can find an almost pure cream example called "creme", I suggest you post it

Comment: I take it you've never been to the USA. 'Creme' is used there extremely frequently, interchangeably with 'cream.' I leave the reasons why as an exercise for the reader. Beyond that I'm really not interested in getting into an argument?

Comment: Been there, seen it used commonly for fake cream, not for real. But your right, we're not getting anywhere.